# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress - Rewrite Dynamic URL

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Here i have kubernetes running on minikube and it has 2 services `backend` and `frontend`. And i have installed ingress addon for minikube.

I wanted to rewrite whenever the frontend request the path url is `/users/{user-id}` it goes to `backend` service with the same url dynamically.

Let say the request is `/users` it rewrite to `backend` service to `/users`, `/users/1` it goes to `/users/1`.

I tried to read [nginx manual](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) found some special expression i don't understand.

This is my ingress configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-be
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /users/$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: backend
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users/(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

My configuration seems fine when the request is `/users/{users-id}` but when the request is `/users`, my ingress won't redirect me to '/users' in `backend` service.

When i tested with curl, this is the output.

```
curl http://backend/users/3

{"id":3,"name":"Sofia","email":"sofia@gmail.com","gender":"Female","createdAt":"2022-04-05T15:46:46.000Z","updatedAt":"2022-04-05T15:46:46.000Z"}%
```

```
curl http://backend/users

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i missing here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried "/users/" with the trailing slash?

Comment: Hi Andreas. This is actually solve my issue!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update!

Andreas in the comment suggest me to use `/users/` and it works!

Then i decided to modified my ingress configuration.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-be
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /users/$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: backend
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /users(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 5000
```